# Show that $x^{-1}$ has finite order $n$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $x\in G$ have finite order $n$.

Show that $x^{-1}$ also has order $n$.

I'm comfortable with showing that $$(x^{-1})^n=(x^n)^{-1}=e^{-1}=e$$

However, I don't feel that this is sufficient to show that the order of $x^{-1}$ is $n$ since I haven't shown that $n$ is the smallest integer such that this is true. What else do I need to do?

Comment: Well, to be complete you should show that no smaller exponent will work.

Comment: Well, what is the definition of the order?

Comment: @lulu Would I be correct in saying that if the order of $x^{-1}$ were smaller than $n$ then this implies that the order of $x$ is less than $n$, which is false?

Comment: Absolutely correct.

Comment: Yes, since $(x^{-1})^{-1}$ is $x$ it should be enough to show that $\mathrm{ord}(x^{-1}) \le \mathrm{ord}(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $x^n=e\iff (x^{-1})^n=e$.